# Writing a program to count spaces in a phrase

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program where a user would enter a phrase, and the program would count the blank spaces and tell the user how many are there. Using a for loop but i'm stuck, could someone help me out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Count
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      String phrase;    // a string of characters
      int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
      int length;       // the length of the phrase
      char ch;          // an individual character in the string

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Print a program header
      System.out.println ();
      System.out.println ("Character Counter");
      System.out.println ();

      // Read in a string and find its length
      System.out.print ("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
      phrase = scan.nextLine();
      length = phrase.length();

      // Initialize counts
      countBlank = 0;

      // a for loop to go through the string character by character

        for(ch=phrase.charAt()
      // and count the blank spaces

      // Print the results
      System.out.println ();
      System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
      System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not homework, just exercise from book where I have to figure out the right loop and condition for the pre-written program

Answer (score 3):

The `for` loop for counting spaces would be written as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++) {
    if(Character.isWhitespace(phrase.charAt(i))) {
        countBlank++;
    }
}
```

It reads as follows: “`i` is an index, ranging from the index of the first character to the index of the last one. For each character (gotten with `phrase.charAt(i)`), if it is whitespace (we use the `Character.isWhitespace` utility function here), then increment the `countBlank` variable.”

Comment: Since this is homework, it should maybe literally count spaces and not just any whitespace. +1

Comment: I see what i was missing, have to declare additional int in the for loop

Comment: Yes, in Java you cannot iterate over the characters in a String, so you cannot use the `for(x : iterable)` syntax. You've got to have a running index.

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop through the characters in the string.
2. Check if the character is a space (char value = `32` or `ch == ' '`)
3. If space, add to countBlank, otherwise continue
4. Display the results.

You might look at the [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [Character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) classes in the Java documentation for assistance.

Comment: So it would be phrase.charAt(char=32)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with java, but if you can access each character in the string.
You could write something like this.

```
int nChars = phrase.length();
for (int i = 0; i < nChars; i++) {
   if (phrase.charAt(i) == ' ') {
      countBlank++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, couldn't you just split the string entered by blank spaces and take the length of the array subtracted by 1?

In C# it would be as trivial as

```
string x = "Hello Bob Man";
int spaces = x.Split(' ').Length - 1;
```

Pretty sure java has a split? Works even if you have two contiguous spaces.

Comment: If you capitalize string and change to lower case Length and Split, would be Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to complete for cycle and count spaces

```
//replace this lines

  for(ch=phrase.charAt()
      // and count the blank spaces

//to this lines

for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
{
    if(phrase.charAt(i) == ' ') countBlank++;
}
```

Comment: ooo i see, declare and interge and then set an if loop within it

Answer (score 0):

You have probably problem with that for each loop

```
char[] chars = phrase.toCharArray(); Change string into array of chars.

for(char c : phrase.toCharArray()) { //For each char in array
if(Character.isWhitespace(c) { //Check is white space.
  countBlank++; //Increment counter by one.
 }
}
```

or

```
for(int i =0; i <phrase.lenght(); i++) { 
if(Character.isWhitespace(phrase.charAt(i)) { //Check is the character on position i in phrase is a white space.
  countBlank++; //Increment counter by one.
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is at the following [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class SplitDemo2 {

    private static final String REGEX = "\\d";
    private static final String INPUT = "one9two4three7four1five";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        String[] items = p.split(INPUT);
        for(String s : items) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

OUTPUT:

one
two
three
four
five
```

The regex for whitespace is \s

Hope that helps.

Comment: I hope You don't get angry for this down vote, but your answer is not a answer for OP question.

Comment: I thought the link was relevant.  Counting the number of items in the String[] items less one would also give the number of spaces right?